# How to store additional data in a mesh?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I'm prototyping a climbing system for my stealth game. I want to mark some edges so that the player can grab them, but I'm not sure how to approach it. I know I can add separate colliders, but this seems quite tedious. Instead, what I'd like to do is to mark mark the edges in the mesh. Can this be achieved? How?

Comment: There is a way to [provide extra vertex data](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexProgramInputs.html), but its intended for rendering. I don't know if it would work for your purposes or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off storing that edge data externally (that is, elsewhere in your running game than in the mesh) in an accessible format, that said, if you truly want to embed it INTO the mesh...

1. Tuck the metadata into Mesh.colors or Mesh.uv2 like @Draco18s suggests. Most shaders ignore one or both of these. Of course, you'll be duplicating edge/face level info for each vertex on the face.
2. When a player tries to "grab" an edge, run your collision test, grab the face, grab any vertex on the face, and look up your edge/face info.

You could also, for example, attach your edge metadata collection to a script attached to the mesh's game object. So long as you can access your collection of edges when you need to perform the test, *where* you store it is an implementation detail.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the ability to add nested objects in your mesh, you could create a primitive box that represents the desired ledge and collider size. When you import the mesh in Unity, the child mesh object will appear as a child gameObject with its own MeshRenderer. You can disable the MeshRenderer for the ledge and add a BoxCollider component to it. The collider will be automatically sized to match the primitive mesh.

[Blender Nested Objects example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukmjg.png)

[Unity Nested Objects example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GFTn.png)

Comment: You could expand this system to have the child objects follow a specific naming convention and just add a script to the main object that procedurally disables the MeshRenderer and adds a Collider on all children with a matching name.